# Laravel Middleware causing user to randomly be logged out

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

So I have tracked this issue down and know the middleware responsible for this issue:

```
class PreventBackButtonMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        return $response
                    ->header('Cache-Control','no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
                    ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
                    ->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
```

The problem is, I don't understand how this particular piece of middleware is causing the issue of randomly logging the user out.

This middleware wraps around all of our routes that you have to be authorized for. We also use a file storage for session, as opposed to redis or database.

**Any thoughts on why this would cause a user to be randomly kicked out?**

The whole purpose of this was to prevent, as the class name states, the back button. from being clicked when logged out.  Every where I look on the internet, this is the right way to do it, but they don't tell you - it randomly kicks you out every now and then, and causes your session to be invalidated, in rare occurrences, when you login. Thus even if you log in with correct credentials you could be booted right back to the login page.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with a different session driver?

Comment: I have not tried to be honest with you, because in a simmilar question, about being randomly logged out people were saying to check the middle ware, when I comment this one out the issues seem to stop. So Iw as thinking its my middleware? @DigitalDrifter